# Serialization issue when running Spark Streaming job

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark

I cannot resolve the following serialization issue that is triggered by `filtered.foreachPartition(iter => {`. I though that `foreachPartition` can resolve serialization problem, but it's not the case. So, how to use `redisPool`?

EDIT (I updated the code to make it more clear):

```
val redis_host = "localhost"
val redist_port = 6379
messages.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.foreachPartition(iter => {
    val redisPool = new Pool(new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), redis_host, redis_port, 2000))
    iter.foreach({ msg =>
      println(msg.mkString(","))
    })
  })
})
```

I assume that the variables `redis_host` and `redis_port` are not serializable, but how do I serialize them correctly so that the code can work on the cluster, not only locally?

The above-shown code throws the error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:919)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:918)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:918)  at
>   org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer$$anonfun$run$1.apply(KafkaDecisionsConsumer.scala:135)
>     at
>   org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer$$anonfun$run$1.apply(KafkaDecisionsConsumer.scala:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)    at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>     at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer
>   Serialization stack:
>     - object not serializable (class: org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer, value:
>   org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer@3fba5c74)
>     - field (class: org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer$$anonfun$run$1,
>   name: $outer, type: class
>   org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer)
>     - object (class org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer$$anonfun$run$1,
>   )
>     - field (class: org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$1,
>   name: $outer, type: class
>   org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer$$anonfun$run$1)
>     - object (class org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$1,
>   )  at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
>     ... 30 more Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:919)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:918)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:918)  at
>   org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer$$anonfun$run$1.apply(KafkaDecisionsConsumer.scala:135)
>     at
>   org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer$$anonfun$run$1.apply(KafkaDecisionsConsumer.scala:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)    at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>     at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer
>   Serialization stack:
>     - object not serializable (class: org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer, value:
>   org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer@3fba5c74)
>     - field (class: org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer$$anonfun$run$1,
>   name: $outer, type: class
>   org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer)
>     - object (class org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer$$anonfun$run$1,
>   )
>     - field (class: org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$1,
>   name: $outer, type: class
>   org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer$$anonfun$run$1)
>     - object (class org.test.manager.service.consumer.kafka.KafkaDecisionsConsumer$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$1,
>   )  at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)

Comment: Could you share the serialization exception?

Comment: using mapPartitions or foreachPartition will help for your redisPool (which is created locally, on the worker and not serialized if you had created it on the master), but are the objects inside your RDDs serializable? it would help if you provided a complete example, including the content of myDstream

Comment: What is `filtered`? Why aren't you using `rdd`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Indeed it was not very clear. Sorry. I updated the code snippet. It's now an exact copy-paste of what I have. Also I putted the complete error stack. Really want to know what's happening with this code.

Comment: @maasg: Ok. Please take a look at the update.

Comment: @PascalSoucy: Please take a look at the update.

Comment: Could you move `redisHost` and `port` within the `mapPartitions` and test?

Comment: @maasg: Sorry, I don't have `mapPartitions`. Actually, redisHost and redisPort are not hardcoded, but are received from class definition `MyClass(val redis_host: String, val redisPort: String)`. So, how should I pass them to the workers?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `foreachPartition`. I'm on mobile at the moment. Search for spark & redis. I answered a similar question before.

Comment: @maasg: I found your answer. Thank you. Just one question. In my case `r.close` does not compile. It says `cannot resolve symbol close`. I am using RedisClient 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to initialise the pool lazily inside your anonymous function. In java you could do something like this:

```
messages.foreachRDD(new RedisFunction(redis_host, redis_port))
messages.count()

class RedisFunction implements F {
    private Pool pool = null;
    private final String redis_host;
    private final String redis_port;

    RedisFunction(String redis_host, String redis_port) {
        this.redis_host = redis_host;
        this.redis_port = redis_port;
        initPool();
    }
    private void initPool() {
        this.pool = new Pool(new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), redis_host, redis_port, 2000))
    }
    public Void call(JavaRDD<> rdd) {
        if(this.pool == null) {
            initPool();
        }
        rdd = rdd.map(....);  /*your rdd transformations go here*/
        rdd.count();   //spark action
    }
}
```

Above java example should help you to fix the serialisation issue.